# parsing a Datetime with AM/PM identifier

Tags: c#, datetime, datetime-parsing

I am needing to parse `Oct 3, 2014 10:05 a.m.`  I'm familiar with using the `DateTime.TryParseExact()` using the `TT` expression for the AM or PM.  However modifying it to `T.T.` does not successfully parse the `string` into a `DateTime`.

Here's the code I have:

```
string dateContent = "Oct 3, 2014 10:05 a.m.";
DateTime parseDate;
bool attempt = DateTime.TryParseExact(content, "MMM d, yyyy hh:mm T.T.", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out parseDate);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.  Let me know if anything is missing, or needs clarification.

Comment: Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.datetime.parse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `T.T.` format is not a standard format as you can see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/az4se3k1(v=vs.100).aspx), so my suggestion is for you to get rid of that with a simple:

> "Oct 3, 2014 10:05 a.m.".Replace("a.m.", "AM").Replace("p.m.", "PM");

**Update**

A more general solution, not being too much overkill by entering into custom `IFormatProvider`s, would be to use a regex like this:

> Regex.Replace(dateContent, "([a|p]).(m).", "$1$2", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

This should do the trick (note that i do not have a c# compiler near by, tough i haven't test it).
What this does it to find for patterns `a.m.` or `p.m.` (ignoring the case) and replaces with `am` or `pm`.

From that point further a `TryParseExact` will work.

Comment: A good suggestion, but how do you handle "A.m." or "a.M."? Although I will admit that those would be pretty rare.

Comment: I was afraid I'd have to do something like this.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: @JimMischel Good point! You grasp it, I'm working on it, though about the same ;)